# exclude gwt super sources from final war

Tags: gwt, maven-3

For a GWT project with following structure:

```
src
  /java
    ...
  /super
    /java
      /text
        /DecimalFormat.java
```

Is it possible to include the DecimalFormat.java only in the project-sources.jar but not in the project.jar(which contains the compiled .class files)?

The POM I'm currently using is:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration combine.self="override">
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/src/emulation/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/src/emulation/**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But all the above don't work because the paths should be relative to the sources folder which is src/java.
Also trying to go up with ".." doesn't seem to work.

Is there perhaps any plugin that handles this more specifically? I've seen some related work from Thomas Broyer https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/add-super-sources-mojo.html. But I couldn't make it work for this scenario.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the `pom.xml` you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I could not make it work with `maven-source-plugin` either (the `includes` and `excludes` filters are totally ignored for some reason). However, it seems to be possible in a multi-module configuration.

### Parent

#### pom.xml

This is one is a little verbose since I implemented it locally up to my code style, but you can sure totally ignore it since it's nothing new and is merely just the parent for two submodules.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-advanced</artifactId>
    <version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>app</module>
        <module>emulation</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>

        <pluginManagement>

            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>

        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

### Emulation submodule

#### emulation/pom.xml

This is the pom for the Java `java.text` package emulation classes. As I said above, I couldn't make `maven-source-plugin` to work fine with the filters, but since this module is separated, the sources can be easily supplied to the target sources JAR file (that has the `sources` classifier automatically).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-advanced</artifactId>
        <version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>gwt-advanced-emulation</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

#### emulation/src/main/java/java/text/Text.gwt.xml

Just a GWT module definition, nothing new. It may be located in the resource library as well, but this is more of a code definition, so it's fine to be here for the testing purposes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>

    <source path=""/>

</module>
```

#### emulation/src/main/java/java/text/DecimalFormat.java

An emulated class just for the testing purposes:

```java
package java.text;

public final class DecimalFormat {

    private final String pattern;

    public DecimalFormat(final String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public String format(final double value) {
        return "{pattern=" + pattern + ", value=" + value + "}";
    }

}
```

### Application submodule

This `pom.xml` does not include GWT build cycle implicitly letting do it on your own. Note the `<classifier>sources</classifier>` element for the emulation module dependency -- this is the most important thing for GWT because it can only compile Java source code, but cannot process Java bytecode. `<scope>provided</scope>` ensures not to attach the dependency to the target artifact (it's not necessary since all JavaScript files are generated and no Java source is necessary while pre-compiling at a server).

#### app/pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-advanced</artifactId>
        <version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>gwt-advanced-app</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-codeserver</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-advanced-emulation</artifactId>
            <version>0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                    <module>test.ApplicationEntryPoint</module>
                    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

#### app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

The module descriptor for the web container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

#### app/src/main/webapp/index.html

A sample GWT application container page to load the application bootstrap. It would display "formatted" *e* and *π*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GWT Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test.ApplicationEntryPoint/test.ApplicationEntryPoint.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>e</th>
        <td id="e"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>pi</th>
        <td id="pi"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

#### app/src/main/java/test/ApplicationEntryPoint.gwt.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.resources.Resources"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name="java.text.Text"/>

    <entry-point class="test.ApplicationEntryPoint"/>

    <source path=""/>

</module>
```

#### app/src/main/java/test/ApplicationEntryPoint.java

A sample application:

```
package test;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;

import static java.lang.Math.E;
import static java.lang.Math.PI;

public final class ApplicationEntryPoint
        implements EntryPoint {

    private ApplicationEntryPoint() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final Document document = Document.get();
        final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###.###");
        document.getElementById("e").setInnerText(decimalFormat.format(E));
        document.getElementById("pi").setInnerText(decimalFormat.format(PI));
    }

}
```

### The output

```
e  | {pattern=###,###.###, value=2.718281828459045}
pi | {pattern=###,###.###, value=3.141592653589793}
```

#### `mvn`

#### Maven commands for the GWT build cycle

- `mvn clean gwt:run` -- Starts an embedded web container.
- `mvn clean gwt:compile install` - Performs GWT compilation (essentially JavaScript files generation), packages a `war` file and installs the artifact to the local repository; the artifact can be easily deployed to Tomcat.

#### `gwt-advanced-app-0.war` artifact listing:

```
Archive:  gwt-advanced-app-0.war
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   META-INF/
      143  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/classes/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/classes/test/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/rpcPolicyManifest/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/symbolMaps/
      349  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   index.html
    11323  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/502BBFC907647230FA696491F4CA7597.cache.js
    11318  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/548A93E7618BA4A5D5DDE22181A086C0.cache.js
       43  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/clear.cache.gif
      317  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/compilation-mappings.txt
    11320  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/E664752A6412123C29A3FFF0FEE4665A.cache.js
    11323  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/E891921037077276BDFB0E285016FD1C.cache.js
    11325  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/FE9CAA3D03DD64BC3E380FCDFFCA4614.cache.js
    14981  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/test.ApplicationEntryPoint.devmode.js
     8167  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   test.ApplicationEntryPoint/test.ApplicationEntryPoint.nocache.js
     1017  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/classes/test/ApplicationEntryPoint.class
       89  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/rpcPolicyManifest/manifest.txt
    32563  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/symbolMaps/502BBFC907647230FA696491F4CA7597.symbolMap
    32544  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/symbolMaps/548A93E7618BA4A5D5DDE22181A086C0.symbolMap
    32548  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/symbolMaps/E664752A6412123C29A3FFF0FEE4665A.symbolMap
    32553  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/symbolMaps/E891921037077276BDFB0E285016FD1C.symbolMap
    32573  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/deploy/test.ApplicationEntryPoint/symbolMaps/FE9CAA3D03DD64BC3E380FCDFFCA4614.symbolMap
      147  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   WEB-INF/web.xml
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   META-INF/maven/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   META-INF/maven/test/
        0  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   META-INF/maven/test/gwt-advanced-app/
     1579  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   META-INF/maven/test/gwt-advanced-app/pom.xml
      106  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx   META-INF/maven/test/gwt-advanced-app/pom.properties
---------                     -------
   246328                     33 files
```

Perhaps there is something more to fine-tune since `WEB-INF/classes/test/ApplicationEntryPoint.class` entry in the target `war`, but the source code of dependencies are not provided.